# How can I convert this arrow function to a normal function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am working on a flutter application and I am trying to convert this arrow function to a normal one, but it is not working

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) => print('Token: $value'));
```

Can someone help me with it please ?

Comment: _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {print('Token: $value')}));

Answer (score 2):

Try this(what I recommend ):

```
var result = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
print('Token: $result');
```

or this:

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value){
      print('Token: $value')
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value){

print('Token: $value');

}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(parameter) => expression;
```

is identical to

```
(parameter){
  return expression;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just start learning, but I believe it will be like this:

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) {
   return print('Token: $value');
});
```